# How can I have my program print and continue instead of crash when a user inputs a 0?

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm having my user input the number of sides that a dice should be.  If someone types a 0, the program crashes. If they type a letter or a float, it prints please enter a whole number. How can I have my program print please enter a whole number when a user inputs a 0? IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence.

```
class Dice():

    def __init__(self, numberOfSides):
        self.numberOfSides = numberOfSides


    def rollDice(self):

        Dice.diceSides = list(range(1, self.numberOfSides + 1))
        return random.choice(Dice.diceSides)

def startRolling():

    while True:

        try:
            userInput = int(input("Enter the number of sides your dice has: "))
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print("Please enter a whole number.")
            continue
        else:
            break

    diceRolled = Dice(numberOfSides=userInput).rollDice()
    print("You rolled a {}.".format(diceRolled))
```

I've so far tried this and it hasn't worked:

```
try:
except (ValueError, IndexError):
    print("Please enter a number.")
    continue
```

Comment: Only break if the number is not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the number after the `try/except`.

```
def startRolling():

    while True:

        try:
            userInput = int(input("Enter the number of sides your dice has: "))

        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a whole number: ")
            continue

        if userInput != 0:
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a non-zero number")
```

Comment: So if the user input doesn't equal 0 and doesn't raise a ValueError, it breaks out of the loop. In general, is this a good method or not recommended as there could potentially be other errors?

Comment: You can check other conditions if you want.

Comment: You probably want `userInput` to be greater than zero, not just non-zero.